# Hyperlink not displayed properly

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, repeater

I want to display data on a page dynamically from database.

I have added a news box and I am displaying events list in repeater from a database. `Hyperlink` and `Marquee` is also used. But hyperlink is not displayed properly.

The code is given below:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID = "HyperLink1" runat = "server" NavigateUrl = "/events/events.aspx?id=<%#Eval('event_id') %>">

<asp:Label ID = "Label1" runat = "server" text = '<%# Eval("event_title") %>' ></asp:Label></asp:HyperLink><br/>
```

Comment: i am not able to see ur code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code as

```
  <asp:HyperLink
    ID="HyperLink1" runat=server
    NavigateUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "event_id", "/events/events.aspx?id={0}")   %>'>
    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "event_title") %>'
  </asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET [HyperLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.aspx) should be declared like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink 
     ID="HyperLink1" 
     runat="server" 
     NavigateUrl="/events/events.aspx?id=<%#Eval('event_id') %>"
     Text='<%# Eval("event_title") %>' />
```